# Changing indent level within one enumerate

Tags: enumerate, indentation, enumitem

Within a single `enumerate` environment from `enumitem`, I would like to vary the indent level. I've seen examples where `leftmargin` is configured at the start of the environment, but I would like to change this value at several points, and preferably have the ability to nest arbitrarily-many levels of indentation. The closest solution I've found uses `\setlength{\itemindent}{}`, but this only indents the first line of each item:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemindent}{2em}
\item \underline{Case 1: $n = 1$.}
\setlength{\itemindent}{4em}
\item In this case, $f$ consists of a single literal, so $N(f)$ is true. Let $g = f$. Then, $V(f, g)$ is true because $f$ and $g$ refer to the same formula. Thus, $p(1)$ is true by construction.
\setlength{\itemindent}{2em}
\item \underline{Case 2: $n \ge 2$.}
\setlength{\itemindent}{4em}
\item In this case...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could use a `\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{...}` but you would lose the ability to put pagebreaks in the middle of an item.

Comment: this looks very confusing. Why do you number the "In this case" parts? They are clearly no new items.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709519/hyperref-conflicting-with-enumitem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use a nested list, and share the top level counter:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{ilist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist*[ilist]{leftmargin=*}
\setlist*[ilist,1]{label=\arabic*.}
\setlist*[ilist,2]{label=\arabic{ilisti}.,before=\refstepcounter{ilisti}}
\begin{document}

\begin{ilist}
\item \underline{Case 1: $n = 1$.}
\begin{ilist}
\item In this case, $f$ consists of a single literal, so $N(f)$ is true. Let $g = f$. Then, $V(f, g)$ is true because $f$ and $g$ refer to the same formula. Thus, $p(1)$ is true by construction.
\end{ilist}
\item \underline{Case 2: $n \ge 2$.}
\begin{ilist}
\item In this case...
\end{ilist}
\end{ilist}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Would there be any way to indent arbitrarily deep?

Comment: @arz You can add an explicit `leftmargin` to the second level definition. E.g. `\setlist*[ilist,2]{leftmargin=2cm,label=\arabic{ilisti}.,before=\refstepcounter{ilisti}`.

Comment: If you want more nesting levels, just change the third argument of the `\setlist` command to the number of levels you need and then adjust the individual levels as needed.  The basic principle is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there also a way to use the same counter for all nesting levels? (For example, "1." could be followed by indented items "2.", "3.", and "4.", which might be followed by an unindented "5.")

Comment: @arz Yes, you can basically use the same code for each level. The code I gave will work for level 3 or 4 etc.

Comment: Sorry, I'm doing a very poor job of describing what I want. The code you gave (copy/pasting a level 3) currently produces https://imgur.com/Z7VsNyz. I would like
1. A, 2. A', 3. A'', 4. a', 5. a'', etc.

Comment: Nevermind, I seem to have gotten it to work (see my answer). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a working sample for what I wanted using Alan Munn's suggestion along with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164623/305602) answer.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{ilist}{enumerate}{4}
\newif\iffirstlegal\firstlegalfalse
\setlist*[ilist]{leftmargin=*}
\setlist*[ilist,1]{label=\arabic*.}
\setlist*[ilist,2]{label=\arabic*.,
    start=\value{ilisti},
    before*={
        \let\olditemii\item
        \firstlegaltrue
        \def\item{\iffirstlegal\refstepcounter{ilistii}\olditemii\firstlegalfalse\else \refstepcounter{ilisti}\olditemii \fi}
    },
    after*={
        \refstepcounter{ilisti}
        \let\item\olditemii
    }
}
\setlist*[ilist,3]{label=\arabic*.,
    start=\value{ilistii},
    before*={
        \let\olditemiii\olditemii
        \firstlegaltrue
        \def\item{\iffirstlegal\refstepcounter{ilistiii}\olditemiii\firstlegalfalse\else \refstepcounter{ilisti}\refstepcounter{ilistii}\olditemiii \fi}
    },
    after*={
        \refstepcounter{ilisti}\refstepcounter{ilistii}
        \let\olditemii\olditemiii
    }
}
\setlist*[ilist,4]{label=\arabic*.,
    start=\value{ilistiii},
    before*={
        \let\olditemiiii\olditemiii
        \firstlegaltrue
        \def\item{\iffirstlegal\refstepcounter{ilistiv}\olditemiiii\firstlegalfalse\else \refstepcounter{ilisti}\refstepcounter{ilistii}\refstepcounter{ilistiii}\olditemiiii \fi}
    },
    after*={
        \refstepcounter{ilisti}\refstepcounter{ilistii}\refstepcounter{ilistiii}
        \let\olditemiii\olditemiiii
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ilist}
\item A
\begin{ilist}
\item A'
\item A''
\item A'''
\begin{ilist}
\item a'
\item a''
\begin{ilist}
\item $\alpha$'
\item $\alpha$''
\end{ilist}
\end{ilist}
\end{ilist}
\item B
\begin{ilist}
\item B'
\item B''
\begin{ilist}
\item b'
\item b''
\end{ilist}
\end{ilist}
\end{ilist}

\end{document}
```

[image]