# Hyperref conflicting with enumitem

Tags: errors, hyperref, enumitem

The code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{ilist}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist*[ilist]{leftmargin=*}
\setlist*[ilist,1]{label=\arabic*.}
\setlist*[ilist,2]{label=\arabic{ilisti}.,before=\refstepcounter{ilisti}}
\setlist*[ilist,3]{label=\arabic{ilisti}.,before=\refstepcounter{ilisti}}

\begin{document}

\begin{ilist}
\item A
\begin{ilist}
\item B
\begin{ilist}
\item C
\end{ilist}
\end{ilist}
\end{ilist}

\end{document}
```

is somehow producing the error

[image]

The error resolves if I comment out `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: With very few exceptions, hyperref should be loaded after all the other packages.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz in this case you need to load it after all the enumitem definitions not just after the package, which looks a bit strange, but....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, right!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz that was true years ago, but now we want to remove these restrictions and if things do not work with a different loading order we try to correct that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you mean that the rule that `hyperref` must, with rare exceptions, be loaded last will no longer apply?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709547/2388

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is an error in `hyperref`. `hyperref` tries to provide a `\theH<counter>` definition for every new counter and uses for this `\arabic{#1}`. But this means that commands in the `#1` are not directly expanded and this falls over here as enumitem uses `\@definecounter{\enit@c\romannumeral\count@}` to define the new list counters and so
e.g. `\theHilisti` looks like this:

```
> \theHilisti=macro:
->\arabic {\enit@c \romannumeral \count@ }.
```

I will change the hyperref definition. A work-around for now is this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\@definecounter#1{%
     \H@definecounter{#1}%
     \expandafter
     \gdef\csname theH#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter
          {\expandafter\@arabic\csname c@#1\endcsname}}%
\makeatother   
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{ilist}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist*[ilist]{leftmargin=*}
\setlist*[ilist,1]{label=\arabic*.}
\setlist*[ilist,2]{label=\arabic{ilisti}.,before=\refstepcounter{ilisti}}
\setlist*[ilist,3]{label=\arabic{ilisti}.,before=\refstepcounter{ilisti}}
\begin{document}

\begin{ilist}
\item A
\begin{ilist}
\item B
\begin{ilist}
\item C
\end{ilist}
\end{ilist}
\end{ilist}

\end{document}
```